# Run rdkit in Conda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, rdkit

I'm having a problem to run rdkit in Conda.

I have installed Conda on Windows 10, then installed rdkit following here: http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html.

When I run `conda list` at the conda command prompt, I have rdkit in the list:

```
rdkit                     2018.03.1.1      py35he980bc4_1    rdkit
```

Now when I activate the rdkit environment (`activate my-rdkit-env`), then launch python (`python`) and try to import rdkit, I run into the following error:

```
>>> import rdkit
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Bakary\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\rdkit\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .rdBase import rdkitVersion as __version__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm actually trying to run Rdkit in Pycharm, but seems like I have to fix the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to resolve the problem following this post [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/message/34936589/) by reinstalling conda.
But I still changed the version 2018 of rdkit when installing.

```
conda create -n my-rdkit-env -c rdkit rdkit=2018.*
```

Everything seems to be working now.